# ¿Como desabilitar dropdown e input en Angular cuando selecciono un checkbox?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Soy nueva en Angular y tengo una duda... En un `dropdown` que tengo quiero que cuando seleccione el `checkbox` se deshabilite el `input`. Pero no se como hacerlo.

Les adjunto mis elementos.

El checkbox:

```
  <label for="utilitario">{{fieldLabels["utilitario"]}}<span> : </span></label>
     <p-checkbox ng-model="all"> Utilitario </p-checkbox>
```

El input que quiero deshabilitar:

```
<div class="ui-g form-group">
  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-lg-3 ui-md-4">
   <label for="precioEstimado">{{fieldLabels["precioEstimado"]}}<span class="required"> *</span> 
   </label>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-lg-9 ui-md-8">
  <input [readonly]="consultMode" type="text" formControlName="precioEstimado" id="precioEstimado" 
   autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" pInputText />
  </div>
</div>
```

Les agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con *ng-disabled*.

```
<ANY
  ng-disabled="expression">
...
</ANY>
```

Si la expresión es verdadera, tendrás el efecto de *disabled*